# Se pueden hacer where opcionales?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, revisión-de-código

Recibo datos de 4 `inputs` los cuales pueden ser opcionales cada uno. Por formula de permutacion no repetida serian 24 posibles casos.

Para no hacer 24 `if` , ¿hay manera de hacer `where` opcionales?

**PD**: es para evitar esto:

```
if(isset($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && isset($grupo_input)){
        $eventos = $pedido->whereIn('EV_cliente',$cliente_grupo)->whereIn('EV_asesor',$asesor_input);
    }
    if(isset($asesor_input) && isset($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input)){
        $eventos = $pedido->whereIn('EV_asesor',$asesor_input)->whereIn('EV_cliente',$cliente_input);
    }
    if(empty($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input)){
        $eventos = $pedido->whereIn('EV_asesor',$asesores)->whereIn('EV_cliente',$clientes);
    }
    if(empty($asesor_input) && isset($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input)){
        $eventos = $pedido->whereIn('EV_asesor',$asesores)->whereIn('EV_cliente',$cliente_input);
    }
    if(isset($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input)){
        $eventos = $pedido->whereIn('EV_asesor',$asesor_input)->whereIn('EV_cliente',$clientes);
    }
    if(empty($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && isset($grupo_input)){
        $eventos = $pedido->whereIn('EV_asesor',$asesores)->whereIn('EV_cliente',$cliente_grupo);
    }
```

Comment: `orWhere()->orWhere()` tal vez te refieres a eso

Comment: muestra como son los datos que recibes y lo que has intentado. también existe el método `when()`

Comment: pues termine haciendo 6 if`s xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de intentar entender lo que buscas, he buscado un patrón para minimizar esos if complejos y he llegado a la conclusión que puede realizarse así con los condicionales, siendo mucho más legible:

```
// Suponiendo que la consulta es al modelo Pedido, 
// voy a asumir una consulta cualquiera como base

$query = Pedido::select('id', 'name');

if (isset($asesor_input)) {

    $query->whereIn('EV_asesor', $asesor_input);

} else {

    $query->whereIn('EV_asesor', $asesores);

}

if (isset($cliente_input)) {

    $query->whereIn('EV_cliente', $cliente_input);

} elseif (isset($grupo_input) {

    $query->whereIn('EV_cliente', $cliente_grupo);

} else {

    $query->whereIn('EV_cliente',$clientes);

}

// finalmente hacemos la consulta
$eventos = $query->get();
```

Creería que es posible mejorar/simplificar aún más este código, pero necesitaría más contexto, sin embargo este es un buen comienzo, mucho más entendible.

Comment: Pues lograstes simplificarlo xD , pero funciona asi y pues tratare de no tocarlo pero gracias por la ayuda pense que habia alguna funcion para opcionales, Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Es bastante potente el hecho de poder realizarlo todo desde el Query, tampoco puedes pedirle tanta «magia» a los lenguajes de programación ni a los frameworks. De hecho tu problema es más de lógica que de programación. Si la respuesta te sirvió, ya sabes qué hacer.

Comment: sisi estuve lejos de una laptop por 1 dia  y no pude puntuar , Venezuela rules :c

Answer (score 0):

Mira a ver si lo puedes resolver con esto, lo que hice fue sintetizar lo que hacías en cada bloque dentro de un arreglo, y con un simple foreach hacer esas operaciones, el problema es que tus 27 condicionales van a seguir existiendo lo que ahora en forma de array:

```
$datos = [
    [
        'condicion' => isset($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && isset($grupo_input),
        'dato1'     => 'EV_cliente',
        'valor1'    => $cliente_grupo,
        'dato2'     => 'EV_asesor',
        'valor2'    => $asesor_input
    ],
    [
        'condicion' => isset($asesor_input) && isset($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input),
        'dato1'     => 'EV_asesor',
        'valor1'    => $asesor_input,
        'dato2'     => 'EV_cliente',
        'valor2'    => $cliente_input
    ],
    [
        'condicion' => empty($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input),
        'dato1'     => 'EV_asesor',
        'valor1'    => $asesores,
        'dato2'     => 'EV_cliente',
        'valor2'    => $clientes
    ],
    [
        'condicion' => empty($asesor_input) && isset($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input),
        'dato1'     => 'EV_asesor',
        'valor1'    => $asesores,
        'dato2'     => 'EV_cliente',
        'valor2'    => $cliente_input
    ],
    [
        'condicion' => isset($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && empty($grupo_input),
        'dato1'     => 'EV_asesor',
        'valor1'    => $asesor_input,
        'dato2'     => 'EV_cliente',
        'valor2'    => $clientes
    ],
    [
        'condicion' => empty($asesor_input) && empty($cliente_input) && isset($grupo_input),
        'dato1'     => 'EV_asesor',
        'valor1'    => $asesores,
        'dato2'     => 'EV_cliente',
        'valor2'    => $cliente_grupo
    ],
];

foreach($datos as $dato) {
    if($dato['condicion']) {
        $eventos = $pedido->whereIn($dato1, $valor1)->whereIn($dato2, $valor2);
    }
}
```

De todas formas echale un vistazo a la sentencia [**when**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses)